# Canvas doesn't take full screen

Tags: javascript, canvas

My laptop screen resolution: 1366x768

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

This code creates 1366x600 canvas (chrome) because firefox and IE creates different canvas width and height. Can it take whole screen? 
**Testing everything in fullscreen**

Comment: are you looking for `outerHeight`?

Comment: Do you mean the canvas doesn't fill up your browser window? Or do you want to hide the browser elements (bookmarks bar, back/forward buttons, url bar) so you fill up the entire screen?

Comment: i want to enter full screen and make canvas to take all the space. and yes i doesnt fill browser windows even without full screen.

Comment: Are you running that code before or after full screening the browser? It works fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the HTML5 Fullscreen API.  Here's a good article on the topic.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

In short, your canvas element asks to be presented fullscreen like so:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.requestFullscreen();
```

The above linked article should explain the details and cross platform caveats in detail.

---

If you want to simply make the canvas take all available space in the browser window, that just takes some CSS.  After googling for "fullscreen canvas" this was the third link, which shows the required CSS to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/qFuDr/

Comment: so without full screen API canvas cant use all space in browser? because even without full screen canvas isint using all the space in browser. isint using just in height

Comment: Did I misunderstand your comment? "i want to enter full screen and make canvas to take all the space" I took to mean you want your content fullscreen and you want the browser controls to go away.

Comment: yes i do but.. the canvas element isint using whole browser space even without full screen and i want to fill all browser space first so i could see just canvas

Comment: See my edit which links to a js fiddle that has a canvas that fits the whole page.

Comment: it works thanks but all my drawings disappeared. FIXED. Thanks again